# Replace part of json (saved as varchar) using regex

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to replace some content inside JSON saved as VARCHAR in Postgres DB. I am using `REGEX_REPLACE` function for this. However, in some cases, it ignores my curly braces and produces invalid JSON.

```
CREATE TABLE expressions (
    id BIGINT,
    expression VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO expressions VALUES
    (1, '{params:[{"value":"test"}]}'),
    (1, '{params:[{"value":"test1"},{"value":"test2"}]}');
    
UPDATE expressions SET "expression" = REGEXP_REPLACE("expression",
      '"value":"(.*)"','"value":{"value": "\1"}', 'g')
WHERE true;

SELECT * FROM expressions;
```

The first row produces correct JSON but the second one is missing one closing curcly bracket and produces this: `{params:[{"value":{"value": "test1"},{"value":"test2"}}]}`.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my expression?

EDIT: I am trying to replace the following: `{"param": [{"value":"x"}]}` ->  `{"param": [{"value":{value:"x"}}]}`

Basically, nest the `value` string into nested json with same structure. This needs to work for multiple values in the column so `{params:[{"value":"test1"},{"value":"test2"}]}` should produce `{params:[{"value":{"value":"test1"}},{"value":{"value":"test2"}}]}`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to replace? Why not use e.g. jsonb_set() to replace values?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Updated my question... basically, I am trying to nest values into a json object but in some scenarios (multiple values in the field), the regex replace handles the brackets incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that by default `.*` will match greedily - so in the second case, your second match will be the entire string up through the final `"` character. Try

```
UPDATE expressions SET "expression" = REGEXP_REPLACE("expression",
      '"value":"(.*?)"','"value":{"value": "\1"}', 'g')
```

The question mark will make the match 'lazy', so it will stop trying to match after encountering the first `"`. The `g` flag will still ensure that both matches are found.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not expect this to be this easy! Works like a charm!

Comment: Excellent! Glad it solved your problem.